# Pattern matching in a file and how to comapare that with another String

Tags: shell-script

I am having a variable like a='Hope'.
And I am having a file containing sentences like
Time delay
go straight
Hope

In this file  I need to find "Hope" only. And I need to compare that with the variable "a".
How it will possible

Answer (score 1):

```
if grep -q -wF "$a" file.txt; then
   printf 'The file contains the word "%s"\n' "$a"
else
   printf 'Did not find "%s" in this file\n' "$a"
fi
```

`grep -wF` will look for a particular word in the given file (`file.txt` in this case).  The `-F` option tells `grep` that the pattern, `$a`, is a fixed string, not a regular expression.  The `-w` option will make sure that you don't get false positives from words like `Hopeless` if `$a` is `Hope`.

The `-q` option tells `grep` not to produce any output. Instead we use the exit status of `grep` to see whether there was a match in the file or not.