# Pattern Matching and comparison

Tags: string

I have a file with these sentences

```
Today is a holiday
May I go tomorrow 
No Holiday
```

From these I need to find `No Holiday`, and I need to compare that with another string, like `grep "No Holiday"!="Holiday"`.

I don't know the correct query. I am just giving a logic what I need.

Comment: Do you need to match `Holiday` to the third line in the file specifically, or to the last line? To compare `Holiday` to `No Holiday`, you don't need the file at all, and you know the outcome already.

Comment: -1 Why do you want to compare these both when you are sure both are different?! `"No Holiday"!="Holiday"` always

Comment: also duplicated of [Pattern matching in a file and how to comapare that with another String](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/396790/72456)

Answer (score 1):

Picking out the last line of the file and comparing it to the string `Holiday`:

```
holiday_line=$( sed -n '$p' file.txt )
if [ "$holiday_line" = 'Holiday' ]; then
   echo 'The holiday line says "Holiday"'
else
   echo 'The holiday line does not say just "Holiday"'
fi
```

Or, if you want the third line, change `sed -n '$p'` to `sed -n '3p'`. `$p` means "print the last line" while `3p` means "print the 3rd line".

If you want the first found line that contains the string `Holiday`, no matter where in the file it is, use `sed -n '/Holiday/{p;q;}'`. The expression `/Holiday/{p;q;}` means print the line that matches the pattern `Holiday`, then quit.

---

Using `grep` as requested in comments:

```
if grep -q -wF 'No Holiday' file.txt; then
    echo 'The file contains the string "No Holiday"'
else
    echo '"No Holiday" was not found in the file'
fi
```

This is similar to [my reply to your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/396793/116858).

Comment: Thank u for the answer.....Do you know how to do this using grep command

Comment: @Ammu See update.

Comment: @Ammu  If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).